# conditional validation in rails redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation

Whats the best way to implement a zip code validation feature. I'm not talking about the format of the zip code, but rather validating that a user entered zip code is one that you do business in. example here: https://doughbies.co/

For example: I only deliver to zip code 12345 so if user puts in a different zip code he gets a fail message saying "we do not deliver to your area" but if the user enters 12345 he is redirected to the shop.

I'm thinking about generating a zip code model with the acceptable zip codes as a constants in an array. Then creating a deliverable? function that matches user input to one of the zip codes in the array constant. Just don't know what methods or validations I can use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a model to represent the order? If so you could have the validation there, without the need of a separate model.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  SHIPPABLE_ZIPS = ['12345']

  validate :zip_shippable

  def zip_shippable
    errors.add(:zip, "cannot be shipped to") unless SHIPPABLE_ZIPS.include?(zip)
  end

end
```

And for how to use this in the controller, take creating an order as example:

```
class OrdersController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params) # "order_params" is params from the form
    if @order.save
      redirect orders_path # redirect the user to another page
    else
      render :new # render the form again, this time @order would contain the error message on zip code
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup, thats exactly how I implemented it. Didnt need the zip_shippale function though. I just used `validates :zipcode, :inclusion => { :in => @allowed_zip_codes }`  Thanks.